# How to retain value in LWC even after changing record or refreshing?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-wire-adapter, rerender

So I have a datatable that contains some information and on Select button click I get that data displayed in another table. But because of re-rendering, when I refresh my page, or when I switch to another record, my selected value does not stay. What are some of the things I could do to retain my information?

I would like for my down datatable retain that selected record upon refresh or changing the record.

[image: select]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use client-side storage to save information even when refreshing.
[Please refer to this documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage)

Super basic Js implementation:

```
// Set an item in local storage
localStorage.setItem('myKey', 'myValue');

// Get an item from local storage
let myValue = localStorage.getItem('myKey');
```

Comment: You can also check this trailhead post: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000Jff28SAB

Comment: This works only on refresh but not with changing records. If I go to my opp1 records and select network1 and then go to opp2 it will display me network1 instead of empty datatable, also if I select something on opp2 and go back to opp1 it will display network2 value not network1. But on refresh it works